# save view in a certain schema instead of PUBLIC

Tags: view, snowflake-schema, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I create a VIEW in Snowflake:

```
USE DATABASE PROD_DWH;
CREATE VIEW new as 
SELECT 
cast(dwh as int) AS dwh_masterclient_id,
FROM INGEST.ISSUE
```

currently, it gets saved in the PUBLIC schema. How can I save it in another location? For example under the Views section of the schema "DBT_USER_MARKT" within the "PROD_DWH" database?

Comment: can you show us the result of ```SHOW DATABASES;```? and ```show schemas;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change context to use the schema you want:

```
USE DATABASE PROD_DWH;
USE SCHEMA DBT_USER_MARKT;
CREATE VIEW new as 
SELECT 
cast(dwh as int) AS dwh_masterclient_id,
FROM INGEST.ISSUE
```

You could also specify the schema in the create statement, or depending on usage the three-part qualifier for the name. Then it won't matter what context is set, it will be created where you want it.

```
CREATE VIEW PROD_DWH.DBT_USER_MARKT.new as 
SELECT 
cast(dwh as int) AS dwh_masterclient_id,
FROM INGEST.ISSUE
```